# Android Studio se cierra

Tags: java, android-studio

(Estoy usando x64 Windows 10 pro) Descargue la ultima version de JDK y de Android Studio, queria aprender a hacer apps de android, hasta el setup y descargar el SDK y el AVD todo iba bien, cree un nuevo proyecto de Hello World siguiendo un video, este decia que al ser el primer proyecto empezaria a hacer ciertas descargas, luedo de la nada se cerro, ahora al abrir android studio se cierra cuando termina el indexing files, no da mensaje de error, solo crashea. Trate ejecutando como admin, cree una variable de entorno JAVA_HOME e incluso descargue un x86 JDK y cambie el path de la JAVA_HOME ya que lei que AS es 32 bits, pero eso tampoco funciono. Me di cuenta que cada vez que intento abrir AS se crea un archivo como el siguiente bajo mi carpeta de usuario:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
```

## EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x00007ffb8c6139af, pid=2152, tid=3912

## JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.10) (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

## Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.10+0-b96-7249189, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)

## Problematic frame:**

## C  [libandroid_runtime.dll+0xb39af]**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando una pc con x64 Windows 10 pro , pero comentas "cambie el path de la JAVA_HOME ya que lei que AS es 32 bits", no deberías realizar configuración de 32 bits en una pc d 64 bits, de hecho actualmente solo se tiene [soporte para versiones de 64 bits](https://developer.android.com/studio?hl=es-419#downloads).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comentas que se realizaron descargas, en este caso la mejor opción es eliminar la caché de Android Studio y reiniciar, mediante:

`File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Borrar el cache funciono, pero ahora esta fallando gradle, la instalación no se completo pero logre hacerlo manualmente, aun asi, arroja este error al intentar correr la app: "Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:" tambien dice "gradle project sync failed"